# Email most, but not all, of the members of a Google Group

Tags: google-groups

I need to email many, but not all, of the members of a Google Group.  I would like an easy way to create an email to my group, but "expand" the list of members so that I can delete a few that I do not wish to include in my email.

One way I've done this in the past is to use Google Calendar.  I invite the group to a meeting, expand the group list, and then use "Email all attendees" to get a list of the members.  The downside of this technique is that you have to create a meeting and invite everyone in the group to it.

Is there another a way to email most of the members of a Google group while not emailing some of them?  I have admin permissions on the group, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

The following, as the OP describe, might work without notifying anyone else.

1. Create a Calendar event
2. Add the group to the invitation list
3. Expand the group
4. Save the event
5. Choose not to notify the guests
6. Open the event
7. Click Email the guests
8. Copy the email addresses
9. Delete the event
10. Choose not to notify the guests

Comment: This works for small groups, but not for large groups due to Google Calendar limitations regarding the group expanding feature.

Answer (score 1):

If the group members list is large, then the group could not be expanded in Google Calendar<sup>1</sup>. One alternative is to do the following:

1. Export the list of group members to a CSV file.
2. Create a list only with the group members email addresses that you want to include in your email message.
3. If the list is short,

   - you could send them an email from your a regular email account
     OR
   - create a new group an email from your a regular email account.
4. If the list is large, create a new group an email from your a regular email account.

**Footnotes**
<sup>1</sup>: Warning message when adding a large Google Group as guest to a Google Calendar event.
[image: Guest limit reached.]